# Full page refresh in Icefaces 1.8.2?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

Icefaces only refreshes the changed parts in the page. In my program I want to do a full page refresh through the manage bean. Does anyone know how to do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a page refresh is easy using the ICeFaces API, you can do it in an action or actionlistener for example.

```
PersistentFacesState.redirectTo(uri);
```

Where "uri" is an URI. This will enforce a browser redirect and refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

To the point: just fire a normal (synchronous) request instead of an ajaxical (asynchronous) request. No idea how to do it in Icefaces as I never used it, but the basic JSF implementation provides you the `<h:form>`, `<h:commandButton>` and `<h:commandLink>` components for that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to let JavaScript refresh the page. There is a elegant way to execute JavaScript with ICEfaces.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(ctx, "location.reload(true);");
```